# How to reduce brightness of LED spotlight permanently without dimmer?

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch, lamp

Some of my LED GU10s (dimmable) produce too much of light and I'd like to reduce it. I'd like to use on/off switch on those GU10s with permanently reduced light. How it could be done and what kind of components I should use?

Comment: Add a series resistor.

Comment: What ratings do your current LED 'bulbs' have - either in lumens or 'equivalent watts'? You may be able to find some other GU10 LEDs with a lower rating and simply swap them out.

Comment: I use Tungsram 350 lm high CRI GU10s, but unfortunately there are no lower rating models and I do not want to mix with other manufacturers. I would opt to around to ~200-250 lm

Answer (score 4):

### They're called cinematic gels

They are just a gray filter that you put over the LED.  You can also get color-tinted, if you are trying to white-balance with other lights.

But a [light one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000I15CAY), and if you need more dimming, add layers.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider a dimmer switch that has a "slider" that is separated from the switch.  This would be completely code legal, give you the convenience of setting the dimming level once and then just use the switch.  You'd also have the flexibility to adjust it easily if your needs change.   Just make sure whatever dimmer you choose is compatible with your LEDs.    [image: dimmer with slider]

Answer (score 0):

Besides series resistors and gels/foils a series X2 capacitor could also help without wasting energy and extending the mean time between failures of the LED bulbs. These mostly rectangular yellow  capacitors can be easily harvested from junk electronics at home or from the next recycling yard and can be located near where the power cable enters the junk device. Trying some values around 100 to 1000nF like  220nF or 330nF  should dim the bulbs. The lower the value, the lower the brightness. These X2 capacities are very safe. In case of using series resistors they  should be also explicitly suited for this application (flameproofed, voltageproofed). Of course all safety requirements must be met, one important is that the series elements must be inside an insulating housing that can only be opened with tools. Both ends of the series resistor or capacitor can have the full line voltage.

Comment: Xeeka, you must be pretty clever when it comes to electronics, but most people are not.  For a newbie to follow your advice could be quite dangerous. And I'm pretty sure most of what you are suggesting isn't code legal.  Let's keep it safe out there!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Of course safety first! My answers are often focused on safety - and energy saving.
One big part of my motivation to answer here was the bare very short comment to "add a series resistor".
So I added the alternate method with an X2 cap (which in general is more safe since no real power/heat is involved) and clearly mentioned the safety aspects.
In general my answers always take the safety into account - regarding others'  statements and even where local codes seem to have important insufficiencies.

Comment: Can you link any capacitors that are UL-Listed (RU-Recognized won't cut it) and whose instructions say to use them directly in mains wiring?  *That is a prerequisite to using in mains wiring NEC 110.2 and 110.3(B)*. Only such product I'm aware of, the LUT-MLC, but that's not listed for series use.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The class X2 is already indicating that qualification for mains usage - and is printed on the cap.
Here you may find those safety capacitors with qualifications like 
ENEC, UL, cUL, CQC:
https://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/capacitors/film-capacitors/film-suppression-safety-capacitors?suppression-class=x2
The series usage is not explicitly mentioned - most likely because the qualification for parallel use would automatically cover the series use, if the device is short cut or has a big insurge current or has a very big wattage thus low resistance.

Comment: ... and normally they are even self-healing! Try to find a resistor that is self healing after a power surge.

Comment: @xeeka either you mislinked, or you need to read [the Q&A here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226521/what-does-ru-ur-label-on-dc-power-relays-mean).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica This seems to be confusing, because:
A click on the pdf-file for the very 1st cap in the link gives this info:
EN 60384-14:2014
...IEC 60384-14:2013 E97863 (approved by UL)
UL 1414:2000
UL 1283:2005 E97863 / E157153
CSA C22.2 No.1:2004
CSA C22.2 No.8:2013 E97863 / E157153 (approved by UL)
CQC (GB/T 14472-1998):1998 CQC06001015331 / CQC06001016454 (C ≤ 10 μF)
UL 60384-14:2014
CSA E60384-14:2013 E97863 (approved by UL)

Typical applications
X2 class for interference suppression
"Across the line" applications
---
I thought this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's the difference between UL the company, and UL the listing.  Contrast that cap with the [LUT-MLC, which has a plainly visible c-UL-us mark](https://amzn.to/3aVcP7m) and whose [UL-approved docs](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/041294_LUT-MLC.pdf) plainly state what it is to be used for, and how to install it. You must install it according to instructions.  Further, note the device provides terminations compatible with NEC 3.xx wiring methods.

Comment: @xeeka the pdf shows that the caps have the 'backwards' UR, which means that they are *recognized* by UL as a *component* to be used inside a UL listed product. The cap *by itself* is not UL listed, and therefore can't be installed alone inline or in parallel or any other way in the mains wiring (to comply with the NEC). The subtle difference between that UR cap and the UL one Harper linked to is that the manufacturer has gone to all the trouble of soldering wires on, heatshrinking the entire assembly *and paying UL to test that the assembly is safe* to be installed according to instructions.

Comment: Yes - technically it's the same thing - and if you peel off the heatshrink all you're going to find is a regular X2 class capacitor with wires soldered to it - but it's the fact that the entire assembly has been submitted to UL for testing along with the manufacturer's official instructions for installation which make it *special* and *legal* to install as a device on its own. source: I work for a lighting manufacturer and sometimes even firmware changes to a smart lighting controller need to be re-submitted to UL for approval ...

Comment: @brhans, Harper 
I could be wrong, but my understanding is that the NEC code does not/can't legally disapprove to use exactly the same - or even "better" parts - and installation methods. F.e. if you take suited/approved components (shrinking tube, wires etc.) and put them UL-style together, the same cap circuit would be installed - w/o  markings. The NEC code often has wordings like "shall", and it does not have the legal status of a law.
But all those beautiful markings would go anyway into nirwana in case of a big heat/fire? How to proof a marked device was installed?

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline dimmer, set it to the level that you want, than forget about it.

Here is one that I've used
[https://www.amazon.com/Low-profile-Inline-Controller-Dimmer-Switch/dp/B00KAFESOE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KAFESOE)

Another
[https://www.amazon.com/Dewenwils-Plug-Dimmer-Bulb-HPID02B/dp/B07CZXLNWL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZXLNWL)

more
https://www.1000bulbs.com/category/in-line-lamp-dimmer-switch/